# React-final-form ignores Field validate property change

Tags: reactjs, react-final-form

On click on a checkbox, I'm changing the "validate" property of another field. The problem is the following: "validate" field is changed and I can see it in React inspector, but react-final-form calls an old validator.

You can see a demo here: https://codesandbox.io/embed/nny0zxz4rm
If you click on the checkbox and then Submit - form will be submitted and validator ignored. If you click the checkbox twice - nonrequired field will prevent form submit.

I can't change the validator's code and can't see any other options to fix this issue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This *does* look like a bug. The field-level validation was not designed with the idea of swapping validation functions so quickly like this. However, until this is fixed, there is a way to accomplish this. https://codesandbox.io/s/pyr69znvnq

Answer (score 0):

Try passing the value straight into the validation fn instead like so

```
type AllValuesInterface = {
   reason?: string;
};
const isOther = (value: string, allValues: AllValuesInterface) =>
   allValues.reason === "Other";
return (
   <Field name="reasonDetail" validate={isOther}>...
```